# Is $_SERVER[REQUEST_METHOD] manipulable?

Tags: php, security

In a PHP project I'm developing I have a couple of requests that can be either POST or GET. Currently, I'm using the $_SERVER[REQUEST_METHOD] value to determine, which request array to use. I know that $_REQUEST values can be manipulated with cookies, is the $_SERVER superglobal vulnerable to attacks?

Answer (score 7):

The $_SERVER superglobal is filled by PHP with data it gets from the web server.

So unless the attacker replaces the web server with his own, or manages an extremely lucky buffer overflow against the server, you are fine.

Answer (score 0):

REQUEST_METHOD isn't limited to POST and GET though - you also need to handle HEAD (IIRC PHP will terminate the script at the first sign of output when it sees that header) and (on unlikely setups) you might get a few WebDAV ones.

Comment: I believe the PHP engine runs the entire script and just throws away the output for HEAD.  It keeps the execution environment simpler.

Comment: It actually stops and send out the headers after it encounters the first bit of content. Some template systems break this functionality by keeping everything buffered until the very last call.

Answer (score 0):

In what sense can $_REQUEST be "manipulated" with cookies? Cookies do override values coming from POST and GET, but *all three values* are directly controlled by the client making the request.

If you want GET and POST to have priority over cookies, you can set the variable request_order in your php.ini:

request_order = CGP

(which gives `post' priority over`get' over cookies). You can even leave out C altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Old thread but since the most voted answer is wrong and security is an important concern, here we go : Not only REQUEST_METHOD but also other values in $_SERVER can be tainted.

See for example http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php#95672
and http://shiflett.org/blog/2006/mar/server-name-versus-http-host

So don't trust them blindly.